# Solving an equation for x when terms innvolving x are symbolic (non-algebraic) expressions

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation

I have something like this:

```
Solve[f[x] == g[x] / h[x], x]
```

where `g[x]` are *symbolic* mononomials in `x` (eg `a[i] b[1] x` for `i=1,...,n`) and, similarly, `f[x]` is a monomial in `x` eg `b[1](1-x)`.

I want to solve the equation for `x`, but *Mathematica* complains that `This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`.

I understand that the reason `Solve` issues the `Solve::nsmet` message is due to the fact that there is `h[x]` in the denominator.

`h[x]` is an expression that is dependent upon `x`, but its exact dependence is not essential for the purpose at hand (think of it as a *constant* that just has to bear a *sign* reminding the user that it is-somewhere down along the line of computations-dependent upon `x`).

I understand that I can `Solve` the problem by simply removing the dependence of `h` on `x` eg

```
{sol} = Solve[{f[x] == g[x] / h, x]
```

will return

```
{{x->h/(h+Sum[a[i],{i,1,n}])}}
```

and I can, in turn, be explicit about `h`'s dependence upon `x` with doing something like eg

```
sol = sol/.h->h[x]
```

that returns

```
{x->h[x]/(h[x]+Sum[a[i],{i,1,n}])}
```

I am asking if there is a less round-about way to achieve the same result.

Comment: But you're not solving for `x` if you're writing it in terms of `h[x]`.  It's fine if that's what you want to do, but it's no surprise that `Solve` doesn't do it.

Comment: It seems like the way you do it is more or less the right way, but this can be automated somewhat with a wrapper function.  Are you happy with having to specify in some way that `h` is to have its `x`-dependence ignored (with something like `ignoreDependence[ h, x, Solve[ ... ] ]`, or do you want the function to be able to 'seek out' unevaluated functions such as `h`?  (The latter case is harder to write and test; you'd probably need to specify more about what kind of functions `h` can appear; and I'm not entirely sure the solution would be well-defined.)

Comment: @jjc385: `h[x]` is not actually a *function* of `x` like eg `f[x]=b[1](1-x)` is; it can be considered an *expression* with *head* `h` and *body* `x`; for the purposes of `Solve`, `h` should be treated as a quantity free of `x`; I understand that what I'm saying might sound weird but in the context I'm working on it makes sense; a wrapper function makes sense as it would essentially automate the process I described in the question; I was hoping there would be a more elegant way of doing it (perhaps `Hold`-ing something or whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[ignoringDependence]
SetAttributes[ignoringDependence, HoldAll]

ignoringDependence[patt_, Solve[eqs_, solveArgs__]] :=
 Reap[Solve[eqs /. p : patt :> Sow[Unique@"ignored", p] // Evaluate, 
    solveArgs], _, Rule[First@#2, #1] &] // Apply[ReplaceAll]
```

Then you can do

```
With[{f = b[1] (1 - #) &, g = #*b[1]*Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}] &}, 

 ignoringDependence[h[x], Solve[f[x] == g[x]/h[x], x]]

 ]
```

> ```
> {{ x -> h[x]/( h[x] + Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}] ) }}
> ```

Note that you could also have done, e.g., `ignoringDependence[_h, ... ]`, though that would have replaced e.g. `h[x0]` (but then put it back in the end, so it probably wouldn't make a difference anyway).

This would work at least in a limited way if you want to solve for multiple variables.

Comment: really interesting use of `Reap[]` and `Sow[]`